# Jquery Wait for animation to finish before leaving the function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an animation inside a function. How can I code such that the animation should finish first before leaving the function?

Consider the code below:

```
ShowBanner.prototype.basicRotate = function (pos, callback) {
    var self = this;
    self.animation = true;

    this.bigbannerScroll.animate({
        left: pos
    }, this.settings.rotateSpeed, function () {
        self.animation = false;
        if (callback) callback();
        console.log('animation done');
        return false;
    });

    console.log('function done');
}
```

Based on the code, the `console.log('function done')` is called first before the `console.log('animation done')`. Is there a way for the first log to be called first, stating that the animation was finished before leaving the function?

Comment: it will not work like that because animate is a asynchronous function, you need to use callback mechanism

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, because animate is a asynchronous function, it will initiate the animation and then returns.

If you need to do something after the animation is completed then you need to use the complete callback.

Answer (score 0):

`animate` is asynchronous, so I don't think there's a way for it to just pause while the animation takes place. You're best bet is to just stick with that `complete` callback function.

Another alternative is to set a timeout (using `setTimeout`) to define yet another function to run after a specified amount of time. But, I can't see the benefit of this.